# Netsuite : personal information (PI) removal

Tags: netsuite, amazon-mws, pii

We have an Amazon MWS API connector that imports data into Netsuite (NS) for shipping and order creation. It is obvious that Amazon data includes PII (Personal Identifiable Information. [Amazon policy](https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/dev_guide/DG_DataProtectionPolicy.html)). Amazon requests that PII never be recorded in logs (in case of NS in system notes).
When an order is created trough a script, NS always places in the system notes the billing and shipping addresses.
I know NS has 'personal information (PI) removal' but this process is manual. we can manually request to process 100 of orders daily.

have you any idea how to remove PI from NS automatically? And stop recording PII logs. Thx.

Comment: System notes are not logs in the traditional sense - they are data change tracking. The more normal style logs in NetSuite would be the script execution logs.

Comment: Yes thx. I know. If you check the NS PI removal, NS treats that as logs (GDPR compliance) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yWmuEaHnhs0.  If you get PI from amazon you should do it too. :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure when the NS added the `N/piremoval` module. We fund it after we payed NS to have a premium support <:). `Magically appeared`. I'll just post the raw code provided by NS.

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 */

require(['N/piremoval'], function(piremoval) {
    function removePersonalInformation() {
        var piRemovalTask = piremoval.createTask({
            recordType: 'customer',
            recordIds: [11, 19],
            fieldIds: ['comments', 'phone'],
            workflowIds: [1],
            historyOnly: false,
            historyReplacement: 'removed_value'
        });
        
        piRemovalTask.save();
        var taskId = piRemovalTask.id;

        var piRemovalTaskInProgress = piremoval.loadTask({ id : taskId });
        piRemovalTaskInProgress.run();

        var status = piremoval.getTaskStatus({ id : taskId });
    };

    removePersonalInformation();
});
```

Comment: PI removal is a feature that has to be enabled in Netsuite. (Setup > Company > Enable Features > SuiteCloud .. and there's a checkbox). Personal Information Removal is basic at best.. not many options IMHO. But it may be good for what you're looking for...